# How to get the list of users registered to firebase using the firebase authentication using angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I trying to check a specific user if it is register on firebase.

I don't need to use firebase database way to check If it exist, I'm looking for something ready like a method support by firebase.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the firestore or the realtime database. I'm not sure going trough a list of all accounts is available (never heard of it at least)

Comment: If you are using email and password or phone auth, you could probably use Admin SDK to lookup for the users. Keep in mind that for this you need to have server side code or a Cloud Function:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data

Comment: Thank you for your replying.